# Цикл while в функции function while() в php

Tags: phpmyadmin, while, php, mysqli

Всем привет.

Прошу извинить за такой глупый вопрос: 
как можно засунуть цикл while в function, если цикл обращается в базу данных? 
Например:

```
<?php
$all = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM article") or die("Ошибка");
   function all_list(){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all)){
      echo $row['id'];
      }
   }
    echo all_list();
?>
```

Comment: @nick_kz, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Передай $all как параметр функции:

```
function all_list($all){}
```

И вызови функцию с передачей параметра

```
echo all_list($all);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можно не передавать никакие параметры в mysqli_fetch_assoc(), она и так знает, что Вам вытащить.

Лучше написать так (если Вам уж так хочется с параметром:

```
<?php
function all_list($connect, $table){
   $rows = array();
   $all = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM ".$table) or die("Ошибка");**
   while($rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all)){
   //echo $row['id']; //нехорошо :-)
   }
   return $rows;
}
var_dump(all_list($connection, 'article'));
```